# AWS detailed Cost Report using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, boto3

I've created a Python script that retrieves AWS cost data on a service-by-service basis for the past 6 months. Subsequently, it identifies the top 3 services with the highest costs, determined by calculating the average cost across all services. What I'm aiming for is to break down the costs for these top three services, such as EC2, RDS, and S3, into a more granular resource-wise breakdown. For instance, if EC2 is one of the top services, I'd like to obtain a breakdown of costs by instances, and for S3, I'd like to delve into bucket-specific costing. How can I achieve this resource-wise cost breakdown in my script?

Please help me with this...

Comment: Is this different from the functionality of AWS cost explorer?

Comment: No, it's the same we have to use AWS Cost Explorer. But I am unable to fetch details within the service

Comment: If you're looking for really granular cost data, consider sifting through the AWS CUR.  (See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cur/latest/userguide/what-is-cur.html)

Comment: That helps a lot, but is there any way of doing it without CUR? Just asking..

Comment: I believe what you're looking for is the AWS Cost Explorer action GetCostAndUsageWithResources.  See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-cost-management/latest/APIReference/API_GetCostAndUsageWithResources.html, specifically, look at the example at the bottom of that page, where it depicts a query which returns costs broken out by EC2 instance id...